# Is it a good idea to name the package "foo.bar.import"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea and I wanted to move some classes related to data import from `foo.bar` into a new package which I named `foo.bar.import`

Idea creates new package for me, but doesn't let me move anything into it. I've tried dragging and also Refactor->Move

[image]

I know that `import` is a reserved word in the source code, but I couldn't find any reason, why I couldn't name a package like this. Is this a bug in Idea or is there some restriction in java language?

Comment: It's a restriction of Java, described in the grammar for *[PackageName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-PackageName)* and *[Identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier)*.

Comment: And a terrible name even were it permitted. It's best to avoid confusing names.

Comment: I don't see anything confusing about let's say `com.company.domainmodel.import`.

Comment: When you say "data import", are you referring to database/file operations? Usually that's refereed to as a DAO (data access object) or ORM (object relational mapping).

Comment: If you'd like, you can think of it like this: You'd eventually have to write the package name in the code, whether it's in classes in the package or other classes referencing the package. And you can't write a keyword as an identifier because Java would interpret it wrongly, same reason we don't use keywords for variables, classnames, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java language specification defines a package name as a sequence of identifiers, and identifiers are defined

> Identifier:
>       IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral

Because `import` is a keyword, it is not a valid identifier and so cannot be used as a segment of a package name.

Answer (score 2):

As @4Castle points out, [package names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-PackageName) are composed of [identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier), which cannot contain [keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Keyword). `import` is a keyword.

I can suggest an alternative package name: `for.bar.domainmodel.dataimport`

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now. I was just confused because Idea let me create such package under /src